# Why "shutdown" can't take seconds as argument?

Tags: window-manager, shutdown

The `shutdown` command can only set timer in minutes and hours, but not in seconds and this suprises me.

From man page

> The time string may either be in the format "hh:mm" for
> hour/minutes specifying the time to execute the shutdown at,
> specified in 24h clock format. Alternatively it may be in the
> syntax "+m" referring to the specified number of minutes m from
> now.  "now" is an alias for "+0", i.e. for triggering an
> immediate shutdown. If no time argument is specified, "+1" is
> implied.

What I try to do is make a button in my window manager (qtile). After pressing this button with my left mouse button I want to shutdown my computer in 5 seconds, but in case I miss-clicked I want click on that button with the right mouse button and cancel this.

`sleep 5; shutdown now` will not work if I want to be able to cancel.

Is there a way to make cancelling work ?
Maybe there is some shutdown-like program with seconds-precission ?

Comment: Did you try `sleep 5 && shutdown now`.  That way, if you interrupt `sleep`, it'll return a non-zero exit status and the short-circuit evaluation will not run `shutdown`.

Answer (score 2):

Following Andy Dalton's advice (see the comment in your question) is the best way to do this.

But if you really want a program to do this, it's easy to write it:

```c
int main(void) { sleep(5); system("shutdown -h now"); }
```

If you place this in `secondsshutdown.c` and compile it with `gcc secondsshutdown.c -o secondsshutdown` it should do what you want.

(This code can be enhanced so that you no longer have warnings when compiling or to make sure that it accepts options. I didn't do this here so that it becomes easier to read)